# Cannot remap Alt-Tab combination after switching Ctrl and Alt

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

On Ubuntu 13.04 desktop I am trying to change keyboard layout.

First in System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Alt-Win behaviour, 
I picked the following mapping:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Win</kbd>.

And that works perfect.

Now I want to change shortcut for application switching (since I swapped keys it is <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> now, I want it back on <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

In System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Navigation, 
I picked new combination for Switch Applications.

It is properly detected as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but it is not working. It still works as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (since I swapped keyboard in first step, it is actually <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Is this a bug ? Is there any way I can change combination for switching applications ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 14.10 I've solved this issue by installing  compizconfig

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In compiz go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher and set "Key to start the Switcher" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 16.04!